# Mapping Elasticsearch nested objects to Hive table columns

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

I am trying to pull data from elastic search to hive by creating external table. So far I am able to map columns to nested properties by using dot notation.
For example. hivecolname: escolname--> emp_id:employees.employee1.id

However, I now have following structure:-

```
    "encounters": [
            {
              "id": 241,
              "admitDate": "2014-12-01T08:04:00Z"
            },
            {
                 "id": 2411,
                 "admitDate": "2014-10-01T08:04:00Z"
              }
           ]
```

Which means encounters property can have any number of elements. I am using following query to create external table in hive: -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName(encounters array<struct<admitDate:string, id:bigint>>) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'ads/dReg', 'es.nodes' = 'localhost','es.port' = '9200','es.query' = '?q=*', 'es.mapping.names' = 'encounters:encounters');
```

However, I am getting following exception when I do Select * from tableName:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with admitDate; given the format ES would save this as a "datetime" whereas you're defining it in hive as "string"; if you redefine it as "timestamp" in hive (or alternatively map it as string in ES) everything should work out.